# SSAS BigInt Formatting

Tags: ssas

I have a few BigInt measures in an SSAS cube which I would like to have comma separated by thousands. But despite trying various formatting options I haven't been successful.

In the measures' properties, first I set the datatype to `BigInt` and set the `FormatString` and `Format` options to `#,##0;-#,##0`. The front-end application didn't show them comma separated (I'm using Kyubit Analysis Portal).

Then I changed the datatype to `int`; The values were now comma separated, but I got negative numbers due to overflows (the numbers for those measures are all positive).

I then tried to change the datatype to `UnsignedInt` and faced the initial issue (the values were not comma separated).

Then I tried the `Currency` data-type and I almost got the results I wanted: values were comma separated by thousands but now I had two 0 decimals that I didn't need (e.g. ###,###,###.**00**)

So my question is: How do you format `BigInt` values in SSAS to have them comma separated by thousands on the front-end application?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a SQL Server 2012 bug. I used some SQL Server 2008 front end tools to browse the cube (including SQL Server Management Studio 2008) and the issue was resolved. I ended up using `#,##0` as `FormatString` option.